# Copy a range from a closed workbook to a specific sheet

Tags: excel, vba, copy

I am currently working on a VBA script to automate a excel sheet. The goal is to have the code open a file from using a file path in cell A2 on a sheet called Reports (the file path is dynamic and is formed using information from the sheet) , copy the data from the file for range A1:E200 and to paste the data into the original workbook on a sheet called HOURS starting at A1. At the moment i have gotten to the point where the file is opened but there is a "Mismatch" error when trying to copy the information across. Below I've attached the code used. I was hoping that someone would be able to help to make sense of the error! I am having the same problem with the close section as well. Note: I am a rookie on VBA so if you could be as clear as possible

```
Sub Button1_Click()
Call Test
Call Copy_Method
Call CloseWorkbook

End Sub
Sub Test()
    Dim strFName As String
    
    strFName = Sheet4.Range("A2").Value
    Workbooks.Open Filename:=strFName
    
End Sub




Sub Copy_Method()
'Copy range to another workbook using Range.Copy Method

    Dim wb1 As Workbook
    Dim wb2 As Workbook
    Dim ws1 As Worksheet
    Dim ws2 As Worksheet
    
    Set wb2 = ThisWorkbook
    Set ws2 = wb2.Sheets("HOURS")
    Set wb1 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Reports").Range("A2")
    Set ws1 = wb1.Sheets("Sheet")
    
    ws2.Range("A1:E200") = ws1.Range("A1:E200").Value
    
    
  
 
End Sub

Sub CloseWorkbook()

  Workbooks("venues_theeway_hours_August2020.XLS").Close SaveChanges:=True
  
  
  
End Sub
```

Comment: Please include something that indicates the line that gives you the error in your question.

Comment: this is the error line - Set wb1 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Reports").Range("A2")

Comment: You have declared `wb1` as `Workbook` and then you are trying to assign a `Range` to it. That's why it's throwing that error. Looking at your code, you don't need `wb1` at all. You can just use `wb2` (which you have set to `ThisWorkbook`). Saying that, I would probably rename them

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this ?

```
ws2.Range("A1:E200").Value = ws1.Range("A1:E200").Value
```

Comment: Set wb1 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Reports").Range("A2")

Answer (score 0):

You're making life quite difficult for yourself there, splitting the code out across 3 subs. Better to

1. rename the references to make them easier to differentiate source/destination.
2. keep it all together so the workbooks/worksheets can still be referenced as they're created:

---

Apologies if I've misread your requirements, my code does the following:

- Reads the original workbook, sheet "Reports", range A2 for a filename.
- Opens that filename as a 'source' workbook
- Copies data from..
- that 'source' workbook, sheet "Sheet", range A1:E200
- ..to original workbook, sheet "HOURS", range A1:E200
- and then closes the 'source' workbook, unsaved as you've not made any changes.

---

```
Dim wbSource As Workbook
Dim wbDest As Workbook
Dim wsSource As Worksheet
Dim wsDest As Worksheet
Dim strFName As String

Set wbDest = ThisWorkbook
Set wsDest = wbDest.Sheets("HOURS")

strFName = wbDest.Worksheets("Reports").Range("A2").Value

Set wbSource = Workbooks.Open(strFName)
Set wsSource = wbSource.Worksheets("Sheet")

wsDest.Range("A1:E200").Value = wsSource.Range("A1:E200").Value

wbSource.Close SaveChanges:=False
```

I'm a little puzzled about your workbook close with save? Perhaps you actually want to close the source sheet *unsaved* and maybe save the *destination* sheet you're adding data to? In that case you'll need to add this line to the end of the above code.

```
wbDest.Close SaveChanges:=True
```